# error OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'

Tags: python, opencv

so im try to use opencv to make extrack picture from video and using this code:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture("D:\danil file\KULIAH\test.mp4")
count = 0 
while vidcap.isOpened:
image = vidcap.read()
cv2.imwrite("D:\danil file\KULIAH\%d.png" % count, image )
  count+=1
```

and somehow it error and says" OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - img is not a numerical tuple
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'"

can u guys help me to make the program run?

Comment: already did and it still same

Comment: `vidcap.read()` returns two variables a boolean and an image. Change the line to `ret, image = vidcap.read()`. If its a success `ret` = True and `image` would contain the frame

Comment: @Jeru Luke. It should be if success ret == True: But the better is if success ret is True:

Comment: syntax error, `viscap.isOpened` is the function, but you have to actually call it! programming requires attention to detail. -- and no, `if ret is True:` is horrible (and so is `if ret == True:`). just write `if ret:` or `if not ret:` (if it's false)

Comment: Python requires proper indentation. Please update your example, so it is visually same as in your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

vidcap.read() return two variables , change your code as below to fix your issue

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture("D:\danil file\KULIAH\test.mp4")
count = 0 
while vidcap.isOpened():
   ret, image = vidcap.read()
   if ret == True: 
       cv2.imwrite("D:\danil file\KULIAH\%d.png" % count, image )
       count+=1
   else:
       break
```

Comment: still error "OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite' "

Comment: You fort=got parenthesis while vidcap.isOpened(:

Comment: can u make the program?

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: added braces to ` vidcap.isOpened()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).